# Cordova Barcode Scanner - Callback functions do not fire

Tags: android, cordova, barcode-scanner

I want to use a barcode scanner in my Cordova application. The scanner itself works, recognises a QR code, prints "found plaintext" on the screen and goes back to the previous page. Then nothing happens. Neither callback function fires.

The code, with which I tried it, looks like this:

```
cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
    function(result) {
        alert(result.text);
    },
    function(error) {
        alert("error");
    }
);
```

Any code that comes after this block works normally. My test device is a Nexus S with Android 4.1.2.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?